# CakePHP not setting the $this->Model->id variable

Tags: php, cakephp, variable-assignment

I am currently trying to access the data that was just inserted using:

```
if($this->User->save($this->data))
{
    $user_id = $this->User->id;    #119
    ...
```

But I get the error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index:  id [APP/controllers/users_controller.php, line 119]
Code | Context
if($this->User->save($this->data))
{
    $user_id = $this->data['User']['id'];
```

I don't understand why the save succeeds, but the id is not set?

EDIT:
So the problem was that because I was using database relations that forced my read to return data from multiple tables, it ended up returning data from multiple tables, so what I really had to do was:

```
$user = $this->User->read();
$id = $user['User']['id'];
```

rather than:

```
$user = $this->User->read();
$id = $user['id'];
```

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `$this->data` before that if statement?  With a `var_dump($this->data)`

Comment: Before the if, the variables are set, except for ID.
After the if, the variables are still set, except for the ID, which should be set by the insert.

Comment: OIC, the issue seems to be that the model is not reloading data from the database.  Correct? Technically speaking you're not trying to access data that was just inserted, but rather data that was created by the database as result of the insertion.  I'm not familiar with CakePHP, but I wouldn't expect it to do so on its own.  I would expect to have to reload that data from the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the ID of the last record this model inserted,you should use

```
$this->User->getLastInsertID();
```

Usually `$this->User->id` is used to make some action know which record it should handle,you cannot use it to retrieve data from database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `$model->data['Model']['id']` is not updated when saving data. Only `$model->id` is. That's all there is to it.